# Go-lang Rock Paper Scissors game

Tags: go

Our project is to make a functional Rock Paper Scissors game using Go. I figured this would be a great place to ask for some pointers on some obvious mistakes I could be making.

I am having several problems.

1. No matter user input the program says I am always entering in "rock.
2. No matter what I input the program also always tells me it is a "tie"

So it's quite apparent to me I am having issues with my if/else statements but I am unsure where and what exactly it is. Also I know my `PlayerPlay` func is ugly but for some reason when I originally had my display menu in there it would keep looping back to my menu without proceeding through the rest of the program.

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "math/rand"
        "time"
)

func ComputerPlay() int {

    return rand.Intn(2) + 1
}

func PlayerPlay(play int) int {

    fmt.Scanln(&play)

    return play
}

func PrintPlay(playerName string, play int) {

    fmt.Printf("%s picked ", playerName)

    if play == 0 {
        fmt.Printf("rock\n")
    } else if play == 1 {
        fmt.Printf("paper\n")
    } else if play == 2 {
        fmt.Printf("scissors\n")
    }



    fmt.Printf("Computer has chose ")
            switch ComputerPlay() {
            case 0:
                    fmt.Println("rock\n")
            case 1:
                    fmt.Println("paper\n")
            case 2:
                    fmt.Println("scissors\n")
}

}


func ShowResult(computerPlay int, humanPlay int){

    var play int
    computerPlay = ComputerPlay()
    humanPlay = PlayerPlay(play)

        if humanPlay == 0 && humanPlay == 0 {
        fmt.Printf("It's a tie\n")
    } else if humanPlay == 0 && computerPlay == 1 {
        fmt.Printf(" Rock loses to paper\n")
    }   else if humanPlay == 0 && computerPlay == 2 {
        fmt.Printf("Rock beats scissors\n")
    }   else if humanPlay == 1 && computerPlay == 0 {
        fmt.Printf(" Paper beats rock\n")
    }   else if humanPlay == 1 && computerPlay == 1 {
        fmt.Printf("It's a tie!\n")
    }   else if humanPlay == 1 && computerPlay == 2 {
        fmt.Printf("Paper loses to scissors\n")
    } else if humanPlay == 2 && computerPlay == 0 {
        fmt.Printf("Scissors loses to rock\n")
    } else if humanPlay == 2 && computerPlay == 1 {
        fmt.Printf(" Scissors beats paper\n")
    } else if humanPlay == 2 && computerPlay == 2 {
        fmt.Printf(" It's a tie!\n")
    }


}

func main() {
        rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())

        fmt.Printf("Welcome to Rock, Paper, Scissors\n\n")
        fmt.Printf("What is your name?\n")
        var playerName string
        fmt.Scanln(&playerName)

        fmt.Printf("Choose\n")
        fmt.Printf("0. Rock\n")
        fmt.Printf("1. paper\n")
        fmt.Printf("2. scissors\n")
        fmt.Printf("Your choice -> ")
        var play int
        PlayerPlay(play)
        PrintPlay(playerName, play)

        var computerPlay int
        ComputerPlay()
        ShowResult(computerPlay, play)

}
```

Comment: In your `main` function, try adding `fmt.Printf()` calls to print out the values of `play` and `computerPlay` in a couple of places.  What values do those variables have?

Comment: You might want to use a [debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) for that or look at [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: If instead of doing `fmt.Printf` directly inside your `func ShowResult`, you return the result string for print (i.e. `fmt.Printf(ShowResult(computerPlay, play))`), your `func ShowResult` can be easily tested with [unit test](https://medium.com/rungo/unit-testing-made-easy-in-go-25077669318). That way you get to check the output of certain inputs matches your expectation.

Comment: `if humanPlay == 0 && humanPlay == 0 ` s/b `if humanPlay == 0 && computerPlay == 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you use a pass by value parameter instead of pass by reference parameter in your PlayerPlay function.

- Function in golang are always passed by value (either 'primitive' or pointer). Pass by value parameters are immutable. It will be allocated new space in memory, different from the `var play`.
- In your `PlayerPlay()` function, the `fmt.Scanln(&play)` attempts to read and copy the value of *the newly alocated space* and successfully did so, but in a wrong reference (not on your `var play`).
- Thus, the `var play` variable will remain unchanged, in its default value (for int its 0). And you end up always choosing.

What you need to do is change your `PlayerPlay()` function to accept reference type, and fill it with reference of the `var play` so that the `fmt.Scanln()` could mutates the `var play`.

Eg.

```
func PlayerPlay(play *int) {
    fmt.Scanln(play)
}
```

And use them like so,

```
  var play int
  PlayerPlay(&play)
```

Notice the `&` symbol is used to obtain the reference (pointer) of the value.